# How to fix Android Studio font issues in IDE menu and labels?

Tags: android-studio, fonts, windows-10

I have just installed new Android Studio. But when I open Android Studio, it shows weird kind of characters. Text and Labels in Menu bar are scrambled / appears to be some kind of garbage characters. Can anybody help me solving this problem? TIK

P.S I am using Windows 10

[image: Screenshot of the issue on Android Studio]

Comment: Uninstalling Bizagi Studio, as here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775813/unrecognized-characters-in-the-android-studio-setup-wizard), solved it to me.

Answer (score 4):

I'm running Win10 and haven't got the nightmare you are into.  My sympathies.  Try this and see if it works.

Navigate to your user data folder.  My user name is "Joe", so my folder is c:\Users\joe\AndroidStudio1.3\config\options .  See screen shot #1 below.

Open ui.inf.xml in NotePad ( I use notepad++ here ).
Change FONT_FACE to "Consolas" - see screen shot #2 below.

Let me know if this works!

Healy in Tampa

[image: ui.inf.xml]
[image: Consolas]

Comment: Thank You for your answer, actually i solved it going through registry of Windows. And was not that easy. Thanks thou' :)

Comment: Didn't help... Still, have the same issue

Comment: Does not work with android studio 3.5, I had to restore the original windows font

Comment: @LuzanBaral can you explain what you did in the registry to fix this problem ?

Comment: @Joe Healy I didn't have all those lines in my file but I added the FONT_FACE & FONT_SIZE ones and that did not work

Comment: @elig i quite don't remember it now, but i went through registry.

Comment: hey I'm having a similar issue but my ui.inf.xml does not have font face ... please help

Comment: I got the same issue. I am using Android Studio 4.0 and don't have ui.inf.xml file in this folder. Anyone please help.

Answer (score 3):

I found out the cause of the issue for the same issue happened in my system. It was caused by the windows font which was somehow not supported by Android studio. I changed the windows font to a standard font e.g. Verdana to fix the issue.

Comment: For me it was changing the system font via WinAeroTweaker , Thanks