# Android Studio showing gibberish characters on UI

Tags: android, android-studio

After installing Android Studio, it's show  gibberish characters, like the symbol font.

Does anyone know what might be happening?

My OS is Windows 10 and my system language Portuguese

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Android Studio font issues in IDE menu and labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523138/how-to-fix-android-studio-font-issues-in-ide-menu-and-labels)

Answer (score 1):

sorry, I did search better now and found the solution here:

[How to fix Android Studio font issues in IDE menu and labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523138/how-to-fix-android-studio-font-issues-in-ide-menu-and-labels)

The solution described is to change the font for the IDE.