# Android Studio and Swing based apps text/ui is broken

Tags: java, android, swing

This is my first time downloading Android Studio and this what I get in the main menu:

[image: All menu options are labeled with random overlapping text.]

Swing based apps have the same problem with the text:

[image]

The code for the swing app:

```java
public class Base {
    private static JFrame JF;
    private static Map<String,JButton> Buttons = new HashMap<String,JButton>();
    
    public static void init(int x, int y) {
        JF = new JFrame();
        JF.setSize(x, y);
        JF.setLayout(null);
        JF.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void CreateButton(String Bname,String BText,int posx, int posy, int sizex, int sizey) {
        final JButton Button = new JButton(BText);
        Button.setBounds(posx, posy, sizex, sizey);
        JF.add(Button);
        Buttons.put(Bname, Button);
    }
    public static void SetButtonEvent(EventActionType EType,String ButtonName) {
        if(EType == EventActionType.CLICKCOUNTER) {
            final JButton Button = Buttons.get(ButtonName);
            final JLabel Label = new JLabel("0");
            JF.add(Label);
            Label.setBounds(Button.getBounds().x,Button.getBounds().y + 50, 100, 100);
            Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                int Counter = 0;
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Counter++;
                    Label.setText(String.valueOf(Counter));
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The main Class:

```java
public class Main extends Base {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        init(400,500);
        CreateButton("Button_1","ClickMe",130,100,100, 40);
        SetButtonEvent(EventActionType.CLICKCOUNTER,"Button_1");
    }
}
```

GPU: Nvidia 1650

CPU: Intel core i5 9600

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523138/how-to-fix-android-studio-font-issues-in-ide-menu-and-labels

Comment: It is probably my font i will check.

Comment: i changed my font to Arial and still its broken

Comment: Did you follow the recommendations from the other post? Someone says WinAeroTweaker fixed the problem. Someone else edited the registry...

Comment: well somehow Android studio worked but swing didn't work it's still broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- **android studio solution**  --

why is this problem occurring?

i think it is because the font your using is not supported, to change it to a supported one, follow these steps:

1. Create a new text file
2. open it and paste in this code

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
"Segoe UI (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Bold (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Bold Italic (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Italic (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Light (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Semibold (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Symbol (TrueType)"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]

"Segoe UI"="Verdana"
```

3. go to file, and click "save as"
4. name it "font.reg" and click on the drop down and select "all files" and then click save
5. before you run the file check the code because this can potentially ruin your computer if you miss up the code
6. run the file and restart you computer

now this is the method that worked for me hopefully it will work for you.

**Have a good day/night**

**Bye**